# How to get Android Studio Memory Profiler as shown in the official document

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler, android-studio-girafee

I am using Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1. The memory profiler looks like the following:
[image]

However, [the official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) shows the memory profiler looking like the following:
[image]

Pay attention to the #2 and #3 features at the top left corner. The profiler in my case does not have the dash line. Could anyone offer a tip on how to get the official Android Studio memory profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1 has the official Memory Profiler. So, you are using the right one. Documentation is outdated and I have logged the following bug to get it updated: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303474260.

Going forward, you can use "Report documentation bug" link at the end of the documentation to file bugs related.

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried to report this from the official document but couldn't find the link. I found it after your tip. Perhaps that link could be replaced with a button along with other buttons at the bottom.